# react navigation 5 header is not shown

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

Using react navigation 5, I want to create a dynamic map for all my Drawer Screens, but the header is not shown with code:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
        {stackNavigItens.map((props, r) => (
          <Drawer.Screen
            key={r.name}
            name={r.name}
            component={({navigation}) => (
              <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Home"
                headerMode="screen"
                screenOptions={{
                  headerTitle: r.label,
                  headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#2e72e8',
                  },
                  headerTintColor: '#fff',
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                  },
                }}
                {...props}>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name={r.name}
                  component={r.component}
                  options={{
                    title: r.label,
                    headerLeft: () => (
                      <Icon.Button
                        name="ios-menu"
                        size={25}
                        backgroundColor="#2e72e8"
                        onPress={() => {
                          navigation.openDrawer();
                        }}
                      />
                    ),
                  }}
                  {...props}
                />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            )}
            {...props}
          />
        ))}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

If I use every createStackNavigator in a const like below, and then call inside component of the Drawer the header shows correctly, I don't know Why ? I think maybe because of the {navigation} arrow function, but don't work too.

```
  const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
<HomeStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#2e72e8',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  }}>
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Icon.Button
          name="ios-menu"
          size={25}
          backgroundColor="#2e72e8"
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.openDrawer();
          }}
        />
      ),
    }}
  />
</HomeStack.Navigator> );
```

[image]